# Is there an Azure Virtual Machine Template for SQL 2014 Business Intelligence Edition?

Tags: sql-server, azure

From what I can tell SQL 2014 Business Intelligence Edition should be somewhat cheaper than Enterprise Edition.  We currently run all our SQL servers on Azure and rent our licences monthly.  I am trying to find an Azure image that contains the BI edition, but have been unsuccessful.

Searching "DataWarehousing" in the Azure Portal gives only enterprise edition options.

Searching "Business Intelligence" in the Azure Portal also gives only enterprise edition options.

The following link for SQL Pricing shows only Web, Standard, and Enterprise Editions. 
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/#Sql

Is Business Intelligence not a supported option in Azure Images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no BI licensing, but you have some of the BI features in Standard images.

**SQL Server Business Intelligence in Azure Virtual Machines**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj992719.aspx/#bkmk_supported_features

There's also a few enterprise images optimized for DataWarehouse and Transactional Workloads.